# Python reads only file created manually

Tags: python, file

I have a code that reads all the files in a folder and finds certain strings from each files, Strange thing is it would only read from files that are created manually. I created a .sql file and the program reads and  gives me correct output but if the .sql file is generated by management studio, it will not read it.

```
try:
    my_file = open("C:/Users/fthoma15/Documents/sqlqueries/billing.sql", "r")
    my_file.read()
except IOError:
    print("File not found or path is incorrect")
finally:
    print("exit")
```

sample code above works with only the manually created file, if i copy the contents in to different file it won't work. 
Output with autogenerated file as below

```
exit
```

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: The script doesn't produce any output except the "exit" message, how can you tell whether it's working or not?

Comment: What is the "correct output"?

Comment: This program opens a file and reads it, but it doesn't print the contents.  And the "exit" message is printed regardless.  The only meaningful output this program will show is the presence or absence of the "File not found" message.

Comment: Its supposed to print the output of the file , not sure what i am doing wrong, the file is present in the above directory

Comment: There is nothing in your script that _prints_ the content.

Comment: Try `print(my_file.read())`

Comment: Still gives me blank output

Comment: Changed the code to my_file = open("C:/Users/fthoma15/Documents/sqlqueries/SQLQuery37.sql", "r")
my_file.read()
print(my_file.read())
my_file.close()

Comment: You're calling `read()` twice.  On the second call there's nothing left to read because you read it already, so it prints nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens the file is not saved because it is still open in another program.
You can debug the problem, try doing this:

```
import os
path = 'C:\\Users\\fthoma15\\Documents\\sqlqueries'
os.chdir(path)
if 'billing.sql' in os.listdir():
    my_file = open("billing.sql", "r")
    print(my_file.read())
else:
    print("File not found")
```